# Exporting report to file using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, report, delimiter

I have a report which I run to extract the content of a "Description" field, which I then transfer to a different system to run a program against the file. Previously, I'd export it in comma or tab separated format. When I try to do this now, whether I use tabs, commas or define my own separator, when I export the data the fields are separated by 5 spaces, NOT the separator character.

I'm doing this:

Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to text

I select either "Comma delimited", "Tab delimited" or "Custom separator" (I tried using "%"), when I run the query & save to file, it doesn't contain any separator value, just the  spaces.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
David A

Details:
SQL Server Studio Manager version 11.0.5058.0
OS: Windows 8.2 (64 bit)
SQL Database version: 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

The "Results to text" option is applied when you choose seeing your query results in text mode (Results tab -  Ctrl + T).

I looked for a way to set a custom delimiter for the "Results to text" (Ctrl + Shift + F) option but I couldn't find one; so I come with a workaround that might works for you:

1. Right click on *your DB name -> Tasks... -> Export Data...*
2. Next on the starting Wizard dialog.
3. Choose your data source (login to the source DB) and click *Next*
4. Choose *Flat File Destinatio*n as Destination.
5. Define the file location (Click *Browse...* or copy/paste the path)
6. Personally, I left the default options; noting that the *Column Names in the First Data Row* is checked. Then click *Next*
7. Choose between both options for your data (*tables/views/query*) and click *Next*
8. If you chose a query, copy/paste it (parse it if you want to) and click *Next*
9. The **Configure Flat File Destination** should appear directly if you chose Table/View as Source and you can select it; or it will show *Query* as the source.
10. **Here you can define your custom delimiter**, the default is ***comma (,)*** and click *Next*
11. I ran the query immediatly, but you can save it as a SSIS package if you need to; then click *Next*.
12. Validate the summary and click *Finish* to see the progress and results of the process.

You can see some screenshots of the process [here](http://blog.winhost.com/exporting-sql-server-data-with-import-and-export-wizard/)

Hope this helps.